# Merge the [sharepoint-migration] tag into [migration]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tags

I recently saw a question with both the [migration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) tag and the [sharepoint-migration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-migration) tag.

- [migration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) has 16 watchers and 840 questions, and a description
- [sharepoint-migration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-migration) has 0 watches and only 67 questions, and no description.

Given that this entire Stack is about SharePoint, specifying "SharePoint" in the tag for a generic term seems unnecessary, and I recommend a mod merge or synonymize [sharepoint-migration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-migration) into the much larger, better described and watched tag [migration](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration), since they presumably cover the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense, and your request has been done as stated below

[image]